# expand a data frame in R

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I have a data frame like below:-

```
                            Var1                  Var2
    1                        a                     a
    2                        a                     b
    3                        b                     a
    4                        b                     b
```

I want an ID column containing values 1 and 2. How do I expand the above data frame so that the final data frame looks something like this?

```
                            Var1                  Var2  ID
    1                        a                     a     1
    2                        a                     b     1
    3                        b                     a     1
    4                        b                     b     2
    1                        a                     a     2
    2                        a                     b     2
    3                        b                     a     2
    4                        b                     b     2
```

Ahh thanks to MKR, the issue is due to the package.

```
      library(dplyr)

df <- read.table(text = 
                   "Var1                  Var2
                 1                        a                     a
                 2                        a                     b
                 3                        b                     a
                 4                        b                     b",
                 header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)



df %>% group_by(Var1, Var2) %>% expand(ID = 1:2) %>%
  arrange(ID)
```

Comment: `bind_rows(mutate(x, ID=1), mutate(x, ID=2))`

Comment: or just `bind_rows(x,x,.id="ID")`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Many options available to get the desired result. But perhaps OP seems to be keen on using `tidyr::expand`. A solution can be as:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>% group_by(Var1, Var2) %>% expand(ID = 1:2) %>%
  arrange(ID)

# # A tibble: 8 x 3
# # Groups: Var1, Var2 [4]
#   Var1  Var2     ID
#   <chr> <chr> <int>
# 1 a     a         1
# 2 a     b         1
# 3 b     a         1
# 4 b     b         1
# 5 a     a         2
# 6 a     b         2
# 7 b     a         2
# 8 b     b         2
```

**Data:**

```
df <- read.table(text = 
"Var1                  Var2
  1                        a                     a
  2                        a                     b
  3                        b                     a
  4                        b                     b",
header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: this is something i was looking for. However I get the error message Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
  unable to find an inherited method for function ‘expand’ for signature ‘"data.frame"’. any idea?

Comment: @itthrill Okay. Lets work out one by one step. Have you tried with sample data.frame shared in my answer? If yes, then have you loaded `tidyverse` package? Also please share version number of `tidyr` package. Most importantly, restart r-studio once.

Comment: tidyr_0.7.2 is my tidy r version

Comment: I restarted. Just for your info the existing column has 0.3mn rows and the ID has 200 . so the expanded table will have approx 60mn rows. Is that an issue?

Comment: on the other hand even if i try to expand by 1:2 , still i am getting same error

Comment: @itthrill Does that solution worked on sample data? First try that and confirm if it works. We'll take from there. 60mn  rows should not be a problem.

Comment: I have tried running it. I have updated the initial comment

Comment: I think you should not load `tidyverse`. Try `library(dplyr) and library(tidyr)`

Answer (score 1):

`tidyr::expand` did not work for me. However, `tidyr::crossing` worked like a charm.

The solution using `crossing` is:

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

df %>% crossing(ID = c(1:2)) %>% arrange(ID)

# # A tibble: 8 x 3
#   Var1  Var2     ID
#   <chr> <chr> <int>
# 1 a     a         1
# 2 a     b         1
# 3 b     a         1
# 4 b     b         1
# 5 a     a         2
# 6 a     b         2
# 7 b     a         2
# 8 b     b         2
```

Data (gratefully copied from MKR <3):

```
df <- read.table(text = 
"Var1                  Var2
  1                        a                     a
  2                        a                     b
  3                        b                     a
  4                        b                     b",
header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's something quite general:

```
library(dplyr)

x <- head(cars,2)
bind_rows(replicate(3,x,simplify = FALSE),.id="ID")
#   ID speed dist
# 1  1     4    2
# 2  1     4   10
# 3  2     4    2
# 4  2     4   10
# 5  3     4    2
# 6  3     4   10
```